# How to filter facebook leads for a set time period

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Facebook API v4 to get a list of the leads(using PHP and the get method built into the library. I want to know how to pass a date range into the request to only get leads between 2 dates.

I'm first getting a list of adets using the following:

```
    $request = $fb->get(
        $account_id . '/ads?fields=name&limit=100&transport=cors',
        $access_token
    );
```

Then I'm looping over those ads id's to get an array of leads:

```
    foreach ($adSets as $ad){
        $request = $fb->get(
            $ad['id'] . '/leads?fields=ad_name,adset_name,campaign_name,created_time,field_data&limit=100',
            $access_token
        );

        $request->getGraphEdge()->asArray();
    }
```

This all works perfectly fine but I want to get a list of leads between 2 dates. The documentation here under the filtering section https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/retrieving/ hints I can pass and from_date and to_date but I can't seem to get that working with my above request.

Any ideas on how I can pass a date range?

Answer (score 4):

You should filter for the field `time_created`

From the section **Filtering Leads** of the [doc here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/retrieving):

> This example filters leads based on timestamps. Timestamps should be
>   Unix timestamp.
>
> ```
> curl -G \
>   --data-urlencode 'filtering=[ 
>     { 
>       "field": "time_created", 
>       "operator": "GREATER_THAN", 
>       "value": 1516682744 
>     } 
>   ]' \
>   -d 'access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>' \
>   https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/<AD_ID>/leads
> ```

Remember that:

> number of seconds since the Unix Epoch

Hope this help

Comment: Hi @Matteo. I see you are having a good experience in developing Facebook marketing API.  I am stuck while doing this process of subscribing to a page from the app. Can you help me with that?

Comment: getting empty result why?