# Facebook Graph API - filtering leads by date using form_id/leads endpoint

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am retrieving leads data by form:

> https://graph.facebook.com/4.0/< FORM ID >/leads

anyone have any idea how to filter by date?

I've tried the approach here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/retrieving
But that is a different endpoint from what I am using (retrieving via adgroup)

Comment: Do you already see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57790532/how-to-filter-facebook-leads-for-a-set-time-period/57795151#57795151 ?